# Tool for designing treeview

Tags: windows, gui, gui-builder

We sell hardware that has a complex configuration with hundreds if not thousands of parameters. To have at least some overview and structure, the parameters are put groups and subgroups etc., so finally you have a tree.

I have cases where I need to argue pro or contra certain structures in that tree view, so I create a mockup of a tree. Today I do that in Visual Studio, using the TreeView control, which is nice, because it has the original look and feel of a tree view. However, the usability of that is very low and it takes a lot of time to achieve the result I want. It's almost impossible to change it during a meeting.

Therefore I'm looking for a tool

- for Windows
- that can easily create a tree view by drag'n'drop
- has good keyboard support (similar to a mind map maybe)
- that allows icons to be drag'n'dropped as well (e.g. from hard disk)
- supports ICO and PNG file format
- that allows me to edit the text of the items
- is gratis (preferred) or costs less than 10 €
- is not web-based. I want it to work everywhere and everytime.

Ideally it has

- a large built-in icon library
- a "find all icons on my disk" functionality

Here's an expected output which I need for discussion with developers (German, sorry):

[image: Treeview examlpe]

I am not looking

- for something to implement myself. I do that today already.
- for a full-blown Mockup tool. Those wireframes are nice in early stages. I need something more concrete at this development stage.

Comment: how about a mind map software

Comment: @jsbibra The mind maps I know have a hierarchical structure, but are not displayed as a treeview, but into all kinds of directions instead. Do you have a specific one in mind?

Answer (score 2):

If a programmatic solution is acceptable, [Essential TreeViewAdv for WPF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/wpf/tree-view-adv) supports creating Treeview easily.

[Example](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/159589/ze/TreeViewSample-1889752962)

[image: TreeView]

1. Can create TreeViewAdv by drag and drop.
2. Up and Down arrow keys selection
3. Set image using  property "LeftImageSource".
4. It supports both ".Ico" and ".png" formats.
5. Edit item by double clicking on the selected item.
6. Supports images and icons generated by [Syncfusion
   MetroStudio](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio).

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

I work for Syncfusion.